# How to use Drupal.ajax() to update #content div on <a> click?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to update the `#content` with AJAX. I've found the Drupal.ajax function and tried to use it with this code, copied from Views module but modified:

```
var base_element_settings = {
  'event': 'click',
  'progress': { 'type': 'throbber' }
};
jQuery('a').once('custom-ajax-processed').each(function () {
    var element_settings = base_element_settings;

    if (jQuery(this).attr('href')) {
      element_settings.url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    }
    var base = "content";// $(this).attr('id');
    Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax(base, this, element_settings);
});
```

But instead of replacing the `#content` it alerts the response contents with the title *An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200*
What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve with Drupal.ajax() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know it can be achievable using drupal.ajax , but created a module for drupal 6 using jquery load and Drupal.attachBehaviors with which you can load any page to any div. Now ported to 7 also :)  this is the [module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/serjas/1713192) (currently under review process)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this presentation might give the answer http://www.slideshare.net/merlinofchaos/drupal-7-advanced-ajax

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#load-content').click(function (e) {
    $('#content').load('/menu/callback/ajax/loader');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Then clicking a link like `<a href="/nojs/path" id="load-content">Load</a>` should fetch and populate `div#content` with the html result of the menu callback from `/menu/callback/ajax/loader`

Comment: do you mean /nojs/path could be /node/some-link ? I am trying to do similar with views, which has user list with link /nojs/articles-by/[uid] , where that path is path of a view of articles with contextual filter uid.When that link is clicked would it load respective articles list in sidebar block?

Comment: ignore my previous comment. I got what I was looking after at https://www.drupal.org/node/2678348#comment-10922187